# Trying to figure out how to show a larger image in pop up box when hovering over a thumbnail in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have been able to figure everything out so far except for this last part where I need to show a larger image when hovering over a thumbnail. I have scoured the internet and stack overflow for hours now and surprisingly have not been able to find such a scenario.
This is what I have so far for the javascript:

```
alert("Your script is working.");   //test

var findImages = document.querySelectorAll(".example");
alert(findImages.length);

function mouseOverFunction(){

}

function mouseOutFunction(){

}

for(i=0; i<findImages.length; i++){
  findImages[i].addEventListener("mouseover", mouseOverFunction);
  findImages[i].addEventListener("mouseout", mouseOutFunction);
  alert(findImages[i].src);   //test
}
alert("Your script finished");    //test
```

The `findImages[]` has all 5 images in it that I need to enlarge upon hovering over the thumbnail with my mouse. Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good way to achieve this,

but just to fixed your code, you need to pass the argument.

`findImages[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
        mouseOverFunction(i)});`

also :

```
 findImages[i].src = "/your/img/url";
 findImages[i].style.display = "block";
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. Are you sure that makes a difference? I put an alert in the mouseOverFunction and mouseOutFunction for testing purposes and the original code seemed to work as it should

Comment: in your **mouseOverFunction** it should be `element.style`, not `element.src.style`

Comment: I don't understand, findImages[i].src already was given a value when I used the function document.querySelectorAll(), so why would I want to hardcode it?

Comment: It's just a Example, I was trying to said that it is `element.style` not `element.src.style` ~

Comment: Ahhh I see. Thanks